# jQuery animation movement

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I'm trying to make an animation of a block moving around the window randomly until you click on it, at which point it will disappear and another block will appear. However I'm getting a weird problem where the block will jump around the screen sometimes instead of sliding around.

Not exactly sure what is wrong with my animation, would appreciate someone looking over it. Thanks!

```
var randomNumber = function(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - 0)) + 0;
}

var newPosition = function() {
  var h = $(window).height() - width;
  var w = $(window).width() - width;
  var newH = randomNumber(h);
  var newW = randomNumber(w);
  return [newH, newW];
}

var moveBlock = function() {
    var newCoor = newPosition();
    $('.gameBlock').animate({
        top: newCoor[0], 
        left: newCoor[1] 
    }, {
        duration: 1500, 
        complete: function() {  
            moveBlock();
    }
    });
```

};

This is my function for moving the block, the rest is on  http://jsfiddle.net/L1qqo06x/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `.stop()` the queue before removing the block.

The queue from the previous object actually was still running and affecting the new one.  `.stop()` kills the queue so it can start anew.

I added `.stop()` before `.remove()` and it acts normally now: http://jsfiddle.net/L1qqo06x/1/

```
$("body").delegate(".gameBlock", "click", function() {
    $(".gameBlock").stop().remove();
    game();        
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It start to jump after you click it because you are restarting the animation but the previous still queued. You apply it to `.gameBlock` class, the new blocks still having that class, you have to stop it before setting up again.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  game();

$("body").delegate(".gameBlock", "click", function() {
    $(".gameBlock").stop().remove();
    game();        
});


});
```